# Dagger: code generation or reflection?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

How do I know if Dagger's code generation is working correctly?  I see several threads where users have eventually discovered that reflection was being used instead.

I have run the example coffee maker application in Eclipse and when I set breakpoints in e.g. Thermosiphon I cannot see any generated classes in the stack.  I do see ReflectiveAtInjectBinding which makes me suspect that my setup is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are a few aspects to this.

1. Dagger has recently removed (or is about to remote) reflection fallback for modules - so you should, upon the next release, not ever have to have reflective module adapters.  If a module adapter was not generated, there will be a specific error that will prevent further action.
2. As to code-generation verification, it is probably worth creating a small verification script that confirms that any sources that contain @Module have a $$ModuleAdapter class generated. Presuming you run in Maven, then this could be attached to the verify step in your project.
3. If you're running in eclipse, then you need to have m2e plugin, and you need to enable in your maven settings to allow maven to configure the annotation processing settings in eclipse.

One caveat.  If you have m2e manage annotation processing configuration, and if you have dagger itself open as an eclipse project, then you must, in the maven settings of your project, disable "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects"

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting it working by adding the 4 dagger jars required for compilation to my Eclipse annotation processor path and then the generated classes were created. With this setup I do have dependencies resolving to workspace projects also.  I have not changed any setting in m2e about annotation processing.